# Excel Time Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have exported a csv list with start tine and end time. After that I have created a new column with the duration differences. How can I make the cell red for >2h and green for <2h? my table looks like this:

[image]

Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Use conditional formatting? What exactly is the problem? Remember dates and times are numbers in Excel. 1 is one day, 2 hours is about 0.08333

Comment: `=H2>TIME(2,0,0)` and `=H2<=TIME(2,0,0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner sir, will it be right to wrap the `H2` within a `MOD()` like this, `=MOD(H2,1)>TIME(2,0,0)` and `=MOD(H2,1)<=TIME(2,0,0)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I would assume that the OP is subtracting one cell from the other and as such the day part does not matter.

Comment: Oh okay, understood sir!